# How to update the content of a P element when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do so when you press <kbd>Q</kbd> the first `p` tag should change from `A` to `Q`, when you press <kbd>Q</kbd> again it should change back to `A`.

```js
window.addEventListerner('keypress', e => {

});
```

```html
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="more text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can determine what key the user pressed by using the `key` property of the `keypress` event. From there you can simply toggle the `textContent` of the first `p` element:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p:nth-child(1)');

window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  if (e.key === 'q')
    p.textContent = p.textContent == 'A' ? 'Q' : 'A';
});
```

```html
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="more text" />
</form>
```